# How to fix "inline error" for Kivymd MDDataTable python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am using Python3 and kivymd for my python app.
I am trying to use the MDDataTable module from kivymd but whenever I run it, it gives this "inline error". Is there anyway to fix this?

I already tried reinstalling the kivymd module but that doesn't solve the problem

Thank you for reading this

[Problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DqQX.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are giving wrong value to orientation

Valid orientations are `‘lr-tb’, ‘tb-lr’, ‘rl-tb’, ‘tb-rl’, ‘lr-bt’, ‘bt-lr’, ‘rl-bt’ ‘bt-rl’.`

> ‘lr’ means Left to Right. ‘rl’ means Right to Left. ‘tb’ means Top to Bottom. ‘bt’ means Bottom to Top.

See docs:
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html#kivy.uix.gridlayout.GridLayout.orientation

Comment: Thank you for your replay.
The error is gone but now it shows : "object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)" after I run it. I added the orientation in the MDDataTable component with no BoxLayout. Did I do something wrong?